# Cloud Functions - View all properties of data() object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking for a way to `console.log` all the properties inside the `data()` object when using `onWrite` in Cloud Functions. Doing `event.after.data()` just gives me [Object object], and that's not very helpful.

```
exports.createSubscription = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userUID}').onWrite(event => {
    console.log('Token: ' + event.after.data().token);
    console.log('Email: ' + event.after.data().email);
    console.log('All: ' + event.after.data());         //Just returns [Object object]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON.stringify(event.after.data())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
const data = event.after.data();
console.log('data: ' + Object.keys(data));
```

Comment: You could also do `JSON.stringify(data)`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have better luck if you don't use string concatenation in your log.  Instead, pass objects to console.log() as individual parameters, and it should expand each object better than you'd get from string concat:

```
console.log('All:', event.after.data())
```